# How do I fix an OpenCV Error npoints > 0 error?

Tags: python, opencv

so I am trying to follow a tutorial using OpenCV in order to compare 2 images with a stationary background but I move 2 markers slightly. The code should be recognizing the changes of the marker, but it isn't doing it for some reason. It continues to return this error. I am trying to learn how to use the absdiff function to accomplish this goal of recognizing the changes, but I commented it out in an attempt to fix the error, which turned out to be unsuccessful.

Tutorial: https://www.authentise.com/post/how-to-track-objects-with-stationary-background

```
File "/Users/Starpool13/Desktop/OpenCV/compare.py", line 26, in <module>
    cv2.drawContours(image_sub, contours, -1, (100, 0, 255),2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-yaf6rry6/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2501: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours'
```

Below is my full code

```
import cv2
import numpy

image1 = cv2.imread('Photos/Before.png')
image2 = cv2.imread('Photos/After.png')
'''
destination_image = cv2.absdiff(image1, image2)
'''
def preprocess_image(image):
    bilateral_filtered_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 7, 150, 150)
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bilateral_filtered_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray_image

preprocessed_image1 = preprocess_image(image1)
preprocessed_image2 = preprocess_image(image2)

image_sub = cv2.absdiff(preprocessed_image1, preprocessed_image2)

kernel = numpy.ones((5,5),numpy.uint8)
close_operated_image = cv2.morphologyEx(image_sub, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(close_operated_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

median = cv2.medianBlur(thresholded, 5)

_, contours = cv2.findContours(image_sub, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image_sub, contours, -1, (100, 0, 255),2)

_, _, angle = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
```

Please let me know any possible solutions to this error, thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try printing out len(contours) and make sure that it's more than zero? Also check that image_sub looks correct by using cv2.imshow()

Comment: Try using a conditional `if(len(contours)>=5): cv2.fitEllipse(contour)` and put that inside3 of a for loop `for contour in contours:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your opencv version is `4.5.1`. You seem to be following a tutorial for an old version of opencv where it states,

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(median, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Based on the documentation for, `findContours` it should be the first variable that has contour. In your case it is getting in, `_` as you are doing,

```
_, contours = cv2.findContours(image_sub, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Try this instead,

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image_sub, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Documentation for opencv `4.5.1`,

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Another option is use try using [older opencv version](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.13/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) with the tutorial link you provided. Here you will be able to use, `_, contours, _`.

Comment: Worked very well, had to add 2 to all your cv variable since I didn't import as cv, but otherwise very helpful. But, I am not that well-versed in OpenCV, and now I am getting an error 

`File "/Users/Starpool13/Desktop/OpenCV/compare.py", line 28, in <module>
    _, _, angle = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
NameError: name 'contour' is not defined
Zachs-MacBook:OpenCV Starpool13$` 

Edit: I think this is a simple fix, but I'm overlooking it somehow.

Comment: Your variable name should be `contours` as defined earlier.